# Three.JS skybox with smooth gradient overlay

Tags: three.js

https://travisscott.com/

This site seems to be using the skybox cube textures that three.js has in their examples. It also has a nice smooth gradient overlay in which I'm not sure how to achieve.

Inspecting their sources, they have an image called pano.jpg: https://travisscott.com/assets/images/textures/pano.jpg

Can someone set me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: They're using webVR panorama like this im pretty sure https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webvr_panorama.html

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/#webvr_panorama